# Where to find English translation of Pansu's paper from Ann. Math?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory, translation, sub-riemannian-geometry

Where can I find English translation of the following paper?

> **P. Pansu,**
> Métriques de Carnot-Carathéodory et quasiisométries des espaces symétriques de rang un. (French. English summary) [Carnot-Carathéodory metrics and quasi-isometries of rank-one symmetric spaces]
> *Ann. of Math.* (2) 129 (1989), no. 1, 1–60.

I actually know the answer and I simply wanted to use it to share the file with everyone. I am sure many researchers will be happy to see the English version of the paper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access the paper here:

**P. Pansu**, [Carnot-Carathéodory metrics and quasi-isometries of rank-one symmetric spaces](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/puinhevgculfewg2vp399/pansucc.pdf?rlkey=7z678swr8owvmm6aj46qya8fr&dl=0) Ann. of Math. (2) 129 (1989), no. 1, 1–60. (English translation).

Or [here](https://www.math.kit.edu/iag2/%7Egabriel/seite/kmx/media/pansucc.pdf).

Let me know if you have problems with accessing the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no guarantee that these two links will remain valid. You might consider a perennial place to deposit it (e.g. arXiv). Have you submitted the translation to the author?

Comment: @YCor This is not my translation. It was done by Gabriel Pallier so it is up to him and Pansu to decide what to do with it. In fact Pansu was Pallier's Ph.D. advisor. I might write to Pallier suggesting posting the paper on arXiv although I am not sure about the copyright issues.

Comment: Just archived on archive.org:

https://web.archive.org/web/20231003062032/https://www.math.kit.edu/iag2/~gabriel/seite/kmx/media/pansucc.pdf